# Will opting in for Google Play App signing for AAB upload affect existing users who have already installed APK from playstore?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

As everyone is aware now Google has made it compulsory to upload AABs instead of APKs. I have an app in play store that has a huge user base who have installed the older version and we **haven't opted** for **Google Play App Signing** from the beginning and now as we are forced to upload the AABs and upload AABs we have to opt-in **Google Play App Signing**. As per my understanding, Google will sign its own certificate on top of my certificate. So I have the following questions for the community to clarify

1. Is there any impact on existing users getting updates after opting in **Google Play App Signing**?
2. Does the user have to uninstall and install the app to get it installed?

Right now we can't test it on other apps as there is no option to upload APKs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opting in on Play Signing does not affect your users. When you enroll an existing app, you effectively have to upload your private key to Google so that they can do the signing on your behalf, so end users will still receive APKs signed with the same key, and thus won't have to reinstall the app.